# Want to remove specific word from URL with rewrite and redirect to correct URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In my there is a URL which contains specific word which I want to remove from URL, but original the request should go on that specific word. For example...

www.example.com/web/un   <--   original URL
www.example.com/web/cn   <--   original URL

I want to remove web from URL so it should look like....

www.example.com/un  & www.example.com/cn

But in back it should redirect to original URL which are mentioned above.

Please help me to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RewriteRule` .Add the following rule to your `server.config` or `.htaccess` .

```
RewriteEngine on

#redirect /web/foobar to /foobar

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /web/(.+)/?\sHTTP [NC]
 RewriteRule ^.*$ http://exmaple.com/%1 [L,R]
 # internally map /foobar to /web/foobar
 RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ /web/$1 [L]
```

This will redirect  `/web/foobar` to `/foobar` removing the `/web` segment from your url.

Answer (score 0):

This will save all after `/web/` on the variable `%1` and you can use it after in your `RevriteRule`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#take care bellow you must use http://www... and not directly www...

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/web/(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /%1 [R=301,L]
```

that redirect `www.any_site.com/web/un` , `www.any_site.com/web/cn` ... `www.any_site.com/nn`

TO

`www.example.com/un` , `www.example.com/cn` ... `www.example.com/nn`

The `[R=301]` flag sets the return code to advise that the redirection is permanent

The `[L]` flag prevents other rules from being applied to this specific rewrite

Comment: it is internally not getting redirect

Comment: I have update my answer (some mistakes). I have tried it and working good. I think that working for you also